# python pandas conditional editing of column values based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a beginners problem with pandas. I took a sample pandas data frame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
               'num_wings': [2, np.nan, np.nan, 0],
               'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
              index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
for i in range(len(df)):
  if pd.isnull(df['num_wings'][i]) == True:
    if (df['num_legs'][i] == 4):
      df['num_wings'][i] == 8
    else:
      df['num_wings'][i] ==6
```

but the value still remains as NaN. How do I change the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out following code :
here ***pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None*** suppresses a ***SettingWithCopyWarning*** which occurs at time of execution,but its just warning, *code will execute without ***pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None*** also.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs':[2,4,8,0],
                    'num_wings':[2,np.nan,np.nan,0],
                   'num_specimen_seen':[10,2,1,8]},
                   index=['falcon','dog','spider','fish'])
for i in range (len(df)):
    if pd.isnull(df['num_wings'][i])==True:
        df['num_wings'][i]=8
    else:
        df['num_wings'][i]=6
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) do to that:

```py
import numpy as np

df['num_wings'] = np.where(np.logical_and(pd.isnull(df['num_wings']), df['num_legs'] == 4), 8, df['num_wings'])
```

This will set the column `num_wings` to 8 when the `num_wings` is null and the `num_legs` is 4. Otherwise will keep the `num_wings` value.